# Raspberry PI only using 4 GB of 32 GB SD card

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, asterisk, freepbx

I'm currently using a Raspberry PI 4 to run FreePBX. I'm using raspbx to run it. So far everything was going good for a few days. Today I started getting a lot of problems receiving calls. I logged into the freepbx GUI and saw that there was no disk space available. So I ssh'd into my pi and ran df -h. I see that /dev/root was at 100%. I emptied out the database cdr and removed log and temporary files. Still only down to 80%. I now see that there's only 3.5 GB on this /dev/root partition. My SD card is 32 GB. So I ran fdisk -l to see where all of my space went. How do I extend my partition to use that space on my SD card?

A screenshot of fdisk -l
https://gyazo.com/5fb9e080a03f4b8d6d18fb6f0e075867

A screenshot of df -h

https://i.gyazo.com/c1b7edee666b7c79e8357a5e10d0bbd3.png

Comment: post text as text not as screenshots, or worse, screenshot links. go read the [`resize2fs(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) manpage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe mosvy is referring to the fact you will need to expand the partition to fit the available free space of the SD card, this should be covered here:

http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/documentation/

Basic Setup
1. Next steps after downloading the image

Instructions on how to write the downloaded image to your card can be found here:
http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup

The image is only utilizing 4GB of your card, even if you bought a bigger one. On a bigger card, you can make more space available to your root partition by running on the console of your booted RPi:

`raspi-config`

Select the option Advanced Options – Expand Filesystem.
If you rather prefer to do this manually, one of the easiest ways is using GParted on Linux. Details can be found here:
http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions#Manually_resizing_the_SD_card_using_a_GUI_on_Linux

Give that a try...